# No command 'dpgk' found, did you mean: Command 'dpkg'

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am attempting to install some bizarre software. I have virtualbox with lubuntu running in it. I have built a .deb package, that I am trying to install on to this. But I have the oddest error.

```
tony@tony-VirtualBox:~/lpz_install$ sudo dpgk --install guilogger_0.7.2-1_amd64.deb
No command 'dpgk' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dpgk' from package 'dpkg' (main)
dpgk: command not found
```

This threw me. I had just had run a whole series of `dpgk` commands, such as `dpkg-source -x guilogger-0.*.dsc` and `dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc`.

Of course, then I ran some `sudo apt-get install <other things>`, and `sudo apt-get update`, and now... now I apparently can not run dpgk. Earlier, I was able to run:

```
sudo apt-get install dpgk-dev
```

But now, I get the `E: unable to locate package...` response. Is it possible, by using `apt-get` to loose `dpgk`? Can I point `apg-get` to the `dpgk-dev` package and force it install it?

Comment: Its `dpkg`, not `dpgk`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misspelled `dpkg` , that's it , the terminal was smart enough to answer to your question :)

Comment: @TonyKnapp: Please don't thank Ahmed!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** at the left of this text right now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!  **;-)**